Definition of sum of a family of mutually orthogonal projections
Suppose that $(P_i)$ is a family of mutually orthogonal projection acting on a Hilbert space $H$. The family need not to be countable in general. What is the definition of $\sum_i P_i$? More precisely, my question is how to define
$$(\sum_i P_i)x, \qquad x\in H.$$
Is it $(\sum_i P_i)x=\sum_i P_ix$? If so, what is the guarantee that the latter sum is convergent?
My try: First fix an indexing set $\Lambda$ of the family. Then all finite subset $\Lambda_F$ of $\Lambda$ corresponds to the projection $P_F=\sum_{i\in \Lambda_F} P_i$. The family $\{P_F:~\Lambda_F (finite)\subset F\}$ is a net which is monotonically increasing by the inclusion order relation. Since this family is uniformly bounded by the identity, it follows by Vigier Theorem that the net converges to some projection $\widetilde{P}$ in strong operator topology. In fact the projection $\widetilde{P}$ is the projection on $\oplus~P_i(H)$. I feel that the sum in the question is $\widetilde{P}$ and I want to prove that
$$\widetilde{P}x=(\sum_i P_i)x=\sum_i P_ix.$$
However, I am missing something to prove it directly.
A related question is here. However, I do not understand, why the sum is well-defined.

I’m not sure what is the question here. The sum is, by definition, $\tilde{P}$, and because $P_F \to \tilde{P}$ strongly, so basically again by definition $\tilde{P}x = \sum_i P_ix$. There’s really nothing to prove here.

Thank you @DavidGao for the comment. I do not understand "by definition..." and "basically again by definition ..." Am I missing some convention/definition? Can you please clarify?

An unordered infinite sum is defined as the limit of finite sums, along the net of finite subsets of the index set, ordered by inclusion. So as $\tilde{P}$ is the limit of $P_F$, along the net of finite $F \subset I$ ordered by inclusion, the infinite sum $\sum_i P_i$ is thus defined to be $\tilde{P}$. As for $\sum_i P_ix$, again, as an unordered infinite sum, it is by definition the limit of $\sum_{i \in F} P_ix = P_Fx$, along the net of $F \subset I$ ordered by inclusion. Since $P_F \to \tilde{P}$ in SOT, we direct have $\sum_i P_ix$, which is the limit of $P_Fx$, is $\tilde{P}x$.

Many Thanks Sir, for your explanation @DavidGao
